# Eagle peek view on a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I am a newbie with graph theory and i am looking for a algorithm to find a eagle peek or eagle view on a graph.
I have a large graph with many number of nodes , i want to show the whole graph in the screen. But then it would be very messy if i am going to show the whole thing as it is.
I was looks for a algorithm which will find prominent sub graphs of the main graph , convert it to a specially marked single node and recreate the graph with fewer nodes. Here the specially marked single node will represent the sub graph we found earlier and it will represent all the nodes in it. Any edge from the rest of the graph to any of the node inside the prominent sub graph would be shown as a connection to this specially marked sub graph.

On pressing the subgraph node , it will zoom in to the sub graph alone.

To do this  i am looking out for a algorithm which will find the prominent sub graphS of a main graph.

Prominent sub graph can be defined as the more coupled sub graph(or set of nodes which have a high number of edges) . Anything that will match this criteria will work for me.

Behavior of the graph

```
1) Number of nodes can span to any number but mostly in degree of 1000
2) Same with the edges. There is no restrictions on how many edges can come but those two mostly related with the number of nodes told above
```

Issues is , the graph would be very large and we cant show it in the screen in any elegant manner. I am looking for such a elegant way to place it.

Comment: You need to give a more concrete definition of _prominent_.

Comment: How you might do this best may rely on the kind of graph you have.  What is in the actual graph you're thinking about?  Specifically, I'm wondering if it's an "organic" graph whose edge degree follows a Ziph or power log distribution.  Also, since we're talking about, what order of magnitude size are we talking about?  (hundreds of nodes?  millions? how about edges?)